# sending Java Serializable Object to Byte Array to webservice java.lang.classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, web-services, arrays, ksoap2, classnotfoundexception

I have a custom object that implements serializable, defined in the client project and in the webservice project. I want to pass that object as byte array through soap message, but when i try to do this, the method in the webservice in rebuilding the object have a class not found exception as in the follow stack:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myproject.biosign.client.vo.Istante
```

Note that the path referenced in exception is the path of the object in the client and rightly that's not found in webservice. How i can rebuild the object with the definition of the same object in webservice?

Following the code of converting, sending and deconverting object.

In client method:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = null;

          out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
          out.writeObject(istanti.get(0));
          byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();

          out.close();
          bos.close();

        request.addProperty("lista", yourBytes);                

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = false;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
        floatMarshal.register(envelope);
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

In WS method:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(lista);
          ObjectInput in = null;
          try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            Object o = in.readObject(); 
            Istante ist = (Istante) o;
            System.out.println("eccoci" + ist.getXCoord());
            bis.close();
            in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Java's serialization the way you have it, you'll need to have the client class `Istante` on both the client and the server in it's classpath.

It is possible to send `Istante`'s byte code to the server, then use a custom classloader to resolve that Class. But I highly recommend you don't do this. A nice simple JSON interchange format would be a better choice.

I should point out the easiest solution is to include the jar with `Istante` in the servers classpath.